# How to add icon to downloadButton in Shiny?

Tags: css, r, button, shiny

May I add my own icon to `downloadButton` or `downloadBttn` (shinyWidgets) in my shiny app?

```
downloadBttn("downloadDataxlsx",
      label = "Download .xlsx", 
      style = "stretch",
      color = "primary",
      size = "md"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> downloadButton
function (outputId, label = "Download", class = NULL, ...) 
{
    aTag <- tags$a(id = outputId, class = paste("btn btn-default shiny-download-link", 
        class), href = "", target = "_blank", download = NA, 
        icon("download"), label, ...)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000001a919c58>
<environment: namespace:shiny>
```

This is the function behind the Download button. Just use your own function.

```
customDownloadbutton <- function(outputId, label = "Download"){
    tags$a(id = outputId, class = "btn btn-default shiny-download-link", href = "", 
           target = "_blank", download = NA, icon("accessible-icon"), label)
}
```

Just insert in `icon` the icon you want and use the function like the normal downloadbutton

How to use it:

#

```
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

customDownloadbutton <- function(outputId, label = "Download"){
    tags$a(id = outputId, class = "btn btn-default shiny-download-link", href = "", 
           target = "_blank", download = NA, icon("accessible-icon"), label)
}

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         customDownloadbutton("myDownloadButton")
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about previous standart icon. May I remove it?
[link](https://github.com/savchukidze/data/blob/master/icon.png?raw=true)

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest using the `shinyjs` package for this. You could quickly change the font awesome class on the download button to something else by using the `addCssClass()` function.

Here is an example of how to change the default download icon to a pdf file icon using it's css selector.;

```
shinyjs::addCssClass(selector = "i.fa.fa-download", class = 'fa fa-file-pdf')
```

Don't forget to include `useShinyjs()` in your UI.